# log4net outputting file but not to debug window

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm trying to get output from for errors to show up both in an appended logfile but also in the debug window. The logfile stuff is working correctly, but nothing every shows up in the debug window.

First, here is my config

```
  <log4net>
    <!--
  This writes the log information to the console window.  It only logs events
  that are at least at the INFO level (which would mean that DEBUG events are not
  captured.
  -->
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newlineExtra Info: %property{testProperty}%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
        <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <!--
  This stores information in the logfile.txt file.  It only captures log events
  that contain the key word test or error.
  -->
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\TOPS\LOGFILES\logfile.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="test"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

and then i call log4net in my code

```
        log.Debug("Debug error logging", ex);
        log.Info("Info error logging", ex);
        log.Warn("Warn error logging", ex);
        log.Error("Error error logging", ex);
        log.Fatal("Fatal error logging", ex);
```

this creates 5 entries in my logfile, but no entries in my console window.

i have also modified my web.config so the appenders were as similar as possible, but i still get the exact same results

```
  <log4net>
    <!--
  This writes the log information to the console window.  It only logs events
  that are at least at the INFO level (which would mean that DEBUG events are not
  captured.
  -->
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="test"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!--
  This stores information in the logfile.txt file.  It only captures log events
  that contain the key word test or error.
  -->
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\TOPS\LOGFILES\logfile.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="test"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

any ideas on what i may have missed that is breaking the console output?

EDIT:

found the solution, as pointed out in the comments below by making3. i confused console appender and trace appender, which is what i was actually looking for. here's the updated config.

```
  <log4net>
    <!--
  This writes the log information to the console window.  It only logs events
  that are at least at the INFO level (which would mean that DEBUG events are not
  captured.
  -->
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="test"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!--
  This stores information in the logfile.txt file.  It only captures log events
  that contain the key word test or error.
  -->
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\TOPS\LOGFILES\logfile.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="test"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your configuration and it works fine for me. How are you configuring this in the code? Is this a console application? Are you expecting this output to be in a Console window, or the Output window in Visual Studio?

Comment: @making3 the output window of visual studio. it's a webservice. now that you've mentioned that i suppose that's part of it? that it's only meant to go to the console window. any idea how to get it to show in the visual studio output window?

Comment: found the solution, you pointed me in the right direction, i confused console appender and trace appender, which i did not previously realize had different names.

Comment: Good to hear, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: @Josh If you have solved the problem, post the solution as an answer and accept it so others can find it easily in the future.

Comment: @AntP oh thanks, i had edited the original post, i wasn't sure of the way to go about that, i will do that now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

found the solution, as pointed out in the comments below by making3. i confused console appender and trace appender, which is what i was actually looking for. here's the updated config.

```
  <log4net>
    <!--
  This writes the log information to the console window.  It only logs events
  that are at least at the INFO level (which would mean that DEBUG events are not
  captured.
  -->
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="test"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!--
  This stores information in the logfile.txt file.  It only captures log events
  that contain the key word test or error.
  -->
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\TOPS\LOGFILES\logfile.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="test"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: This was driving me crazy!  I was able to setup logging in node.js with log4js < 5 mins, trying to use log4net took so long because I thought the vs debug window WAS the console, so I was mistakenly using the ConsoleAppender as well once I figured out the janky xml config for log4net.